# Android: Replace Notification Bar

Tags: android

currently I'm working on an UI Replacement of Android, currently achived by writing a different launcher and different-styled apps. All's good so far, BUT: there is still the notification bar missing, means, I have no idea how to replace the notification bar.

The "new" notification bar shall show only generic informations like the clock and network state, similar to windows phone and ios, without NotificationManager-binding.

How can I achive this? I know that there are several notification bar replacement apps out there, like omega statusbar or statusbar+.

My idea was to make every app of my UI fullscreen and having its own NotificationBar-Instance, fed by a ContentProvider or Service. But if the user decides to use classic android apps, he also will see the generic notification bar, which isn't what I want.

Also it might be an idea to create a window on top the notification bar, but I have no clue either this is "the right way", nor if it is even possible to achive this in this way.

Comment: Your might need to override the `framework-res.apk` file to have that functionality..

Comment: And also you may need to get the source of that `apk` and redesign the notifications bar and build it again.. I'm not sure about this however.

Comment: Am I right that this way will make it unable to use a different notification bar without root?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but I think without root you can't override android's notifications bar but however it's still possible to implement a full screen view which you said is not good.

Comment: but how do omega statusbar and statusbar+ achive this functionality without any system / app modification?

Comment: Ok I looked at those apps' permissions and I noticed that they draw over other apps. That is the tricks. ;) You need to make your app draw over other apps the notifications bar. Keep in mind that you will need to receive some intents and add new notifications to your notification bar too.

Comment: so this might be the windowed way I mentioned? Also I don't want to show notifications in the notification bar, as mentioned fore, like on iOS or Windows Phone

Comment: Look at this link, [Example](http://iserveandroid.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-to-implement-your-own-status-bar.html) It might help you, or atleast it will give idea for your problem..

Comment: link: http://iserveandroid.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-to-implement-your-own-status-bar.html